# Get value of hidden type

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to get the value of **csrf** and **tp_redirect_id** from https://fremdgehen69.com .

I tried

```
import requests_html

session = requests_html.HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://fremdgehen69.com', verify = False)

print(r.html.xpath('//*[@id="auth:RegistrationForm:multistep[signupForm]"]/input[1]')[0].attrs['value'])
print(r.html.xpath('//*[@id="auth:RegistrationForm:multistep[signupForm]"]/input[2]')[0].attrs['value'])
```

and it's working for **csrf** but not for **tp_redirect_id**. Why?

Output:

```
/Users/x/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:1043: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'fremdgehen69.com'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  warnings.warn(
44df6cd02ab9e8d6e5a77a5f21251f48
```

44df6cd02ab9e8d6e5a77a5f21251f48 is **csrf** and **tp_redirect_id** is blank.

Answer (score 0):

Okay now it's working. I added

```
r.html.render(sleep = 5)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).